# Installing Pajek on M1 Mac

Tags: macos, wine

I'm trying to install Pajek on a M1 Mac, Big Sur 11.2.3. I've tried installing Wine, using Homebrew and using the command `brew install wine`, followed by `wine Pajek.exe` and `wine64 Pajek.exe`. I also tried this solution given [here](http://mrvar.fdv.uni-lj.si/pajek/MAC/PajekOSX1.pdf), which I cannot get past step 4 and get an error saying "Prefix creation exited with error".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Wine (originally an acronym for "**Wine Is Not an Emulator**") is a compatibility layer capable of running Windows applications on several POSIX-compliant operating systems, such as Linux, macOS, & BSD. Instead of simulating internal Windows logic like a virtual machine or emulator, Wine translates Windows API calls into POSIX calls on-the-fly, eliminating the performance and memory penalties of other methods and allowing you to cleanly integrate Windows applications into your desktop.

I quote the above from [the WINE homepage](https://www.winehq.org/) because it needs to be said that **Wine Is Not an Emulator**.

Your Mac has an ARM based M1 processor. The program you are running ([this one?](http://mrvar.fdv.uni-lj.si/pajek/)) is an x86-64 executable. Because **Wine Is Not an Emulator** it cannot convert x86 code into ARM code. WINE expects the machine architectures to match, so even if you have an ARM capable version of WINE, you need a native Windows ARM version of Pajek as well. Given the only Windows device running ARM that I know of is the Surface Pro X there is little reason for the software developers to port their code to run on Windows on ARM.

You either need to recompile Pajek for your platform, or run it on an x86 (Intel/AMD) platform Mac rather than the ARM M1 processor that you have.

**You cannot run this program on the computer you have in the way you are trying to do.**

---

Apparently [there are some hacky methods](https://wiki.winehq.org/Emulation) to emulate x86 on ARM, but this is delving into the territory of "if you have to ask you really don't want to know" type rabbit holes. If you are already stuck at running something on a platform it was never designed for (MacOS ARM), using a tool that barely manages to glue two *other* different platforms together (Linux & Windows) then this is just a whole other world of pain. At the very least there are significant performance implications of that emulation that for serious tasks beyond running "light programs" would be a real show stopper.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation. I'm gonna go look into the hacky methods you mentioned. What do you mean by recompiling Pajek? I did some quick Googling but is this something I'd be able to do given a rather limited knowledge of softwares/computers?

Comment: The hacky methods are basically to set up machine emulation. Programs like `qemu` and `bochs` will allow you to emulate a full computer and it may be a better (if slower) option to just go down that route and ignore wine entirely. If getting a real x86 processor is not an option and you don't mind it being slow then it might well be "simpler" to just install an old copy of Windows in one of those emulators. To be able to recompile it yourself would need all of the source code and a good amount of knowledge of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same problem and I just fix it. Using Wine up to 6.0.1

The steps:

1. `brew install --cask xquartz`
2. `brew install --cask --no-quarantine wine-stable`
3. Download the Zip file of paject to 64.
4. `wine64 Pajek.exe`